# What do the US and Australian governments gain from a US Marine presence in Darwin?

Tags: united-states, australia, military

The US has decided to establish a [US Marine presence in Darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_Rotational_Force_%E2%80%93_Darwin). What do benefits do both governments gain from this?

Answer (score 8):

Australia gets

- economic benefits inherent with hosting a military base

  Even the opponents of the base (Australian Green Party) admit that:

  > The economic benefits of military bases include employment for local contractors and suppliers.
- military benefits of both joint training exercises
- better security, especially in light of much stronger Chinese geopolitical weight and power projection, coupled with Japanese resurgence as maritime power - the latter is a very long term concern, granted, but some people still remember the meaning of [Greater East-Asian Co-Prosperity Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_East_Asia_Co-Prosperity_Sphere).

---

USA gets a base in an important strategic location, in an extremely friendly territory, [close to South-East Asia](http://goo.gl/maps/sRFXo) (next door to both Philippines and Indonesia, both countries with Islamist and Al-Quaida franchise presence) and closer to China. This is in line with Obama Administration announced 2011 strategic pivot to interests in Asia-Pacific region.

A pretty good list of strategic implications and benefits can be found in this comprehensive article by [Gordon Arthur](http://www.asiapacificdefencereporter.com/articles/266/US-MARINE-DEPLOYMENT-IN-DARWIN-BORDERING-ON-THE-REMARKABLE).

This is extremely important in light of issues inherent in stationing and basing in Islamic countries (if you recall, Osama Bin Laden's **main** original stated beef with the USA - outside of their support for House Saud - was the US forces based in Saudi Arabia)

Comment: You forgot that Australia also gets dragged into the War on Overseas Oil Production.

Answer (score 0):

To the answer of user4012 I would add an important point that is:

- Stricter control over the sea area shared by Australia, Timor East and Indonesia which contains important oil and gas fields.

https://www.poweroilandgas.com/2011/11/timor-leste-oil-and-gas-industry.html

https://www.laohamutuk.org/OilWeb/OTD_FS/Laminria.htm